# Booststrap form doesn't work

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit

Please I'm trying to use bootstrap to change my website look however when I try to change the form of my login page it seems to load when i click on submit, but does nothing. Any help !!

Old code :

```
<form method="post" name="login" action="">
<table align="center">
<tr><td>
    <table align="center">
            <tr>
               <td align="right"><font face="Arial,Helvetica" size="-1"><strong>Username:</strong></font></td>
               <td align="left"><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td align="right" width="30%"><font face="Arial,Helvetica" size="-1"><strong>Password:</strong></font></td>
               <td align="left"><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <center><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></center>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

New code :

```
<div class="container">

<form class="form-signin" role="form"  method="post" name="login" action="">
   <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <!--center><input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></center-->
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">Sign in</button>
</form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot the attribute `name` in the `input`, try this:

```
<div class="container">    
<form class="form-signin" role="form"  method="post" name="login" action="">
   <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <!--center><input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></center-->
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">Sign in</button>
</form>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="login" action="">
```

Did you intentionally leave action blank? Without an action for it to post to, of course it's going to do nothing.